# Is System-F with higher-kinded newtypes equivalent in computational power to System-F omega?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, type-systems, typed-lambda-calculus

If we have System-F with higher-kinded types and newtypes, then we can express everything (I think) of System-F omega, except we have to manually (un)pack.
For example:

```
newtype List t = List (forall r. r -> (t -> r -> r) -> r)

unList :: List t -> (forall r. r -> (t -> r -> r) -> r)
unList (List f) = f
```

Is (I think) equivalent to System-F omega:

```
List = \t. forall r. r -> (t -> r -> r) -> r
```

Except you have to call `List` and `unList` at the right moments.

Does this language with newtypes have more computation strength than System-F, equal to System-F omega?

Comment: Aside: the relationship between $F$ and $F_{\omega}$ is not well-understood. Pawel Urzyczyn conjectured that  $F_{\omega}$ is equivalent to typablility in $F_1$ (which is $F$ with first-order kinding).

Comment: @MartinBerger for typing individual terms: obviously there are functions which are well typed both in system $F_\omega$ and system $F$, but that can only be actually used in system $F_\omega$.

Comment: @cody I'm referring to Problem 12 in the [TLCA List of Open Problems](http://tlca.di.unito.it/opltlca/opltlca.pdf).

Comment: @MartinBerger I am familiar with the problem, but there is a subtle point here, which is that there are *functions* definable in $F_\omega$, which cannot be defined in $F$, if the function is to be taken $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @cody. By definable you mean semantically definable, not syntax? Aside, the conjecture is about $F_1$ vs $F_{\omega}$, that's what you meant?

Comment: @MartinBerger semantically definable, yes. And I did mean system $F$, but the argument generalizes to $F_1$.

Comment: @cody What blocks us from turning this semantic insight into a solution for #12 of TLCA's open problems?

Comment: @MartinBerger The fact that giving a type to an *individual term* is different than giving it a type *as a function from naturals to naturals*. E.g. *every normal form* can be typed in system F (curry style). Certainly, though, not every function from the untyped $\lambda$-calculus can be turned into a function in system F.